# Convert Time Stamp into date, time, hour, minute

Tags: r, datetime, lubridate

I have a column in my dataset that is below:

```
df$timestamp

timestamp
2018-01-17 10:35:00 UTC
2015-05-08 17:30:00 UTC
2017-11-22 07:15:00 UTC
2017-12-05 07:30:00 UTC

str(timestamp)
chr [1:1196940] "2018-01-17 10:35:00 UTC" "2015-05-08 17:30:00 UTC" "2017-11-22 07:15:00 UTC" "2017-12-05 07:30:00 UTC" ...
```

I want to be able to extract the the year-month-day and then time separately.

My final output is supposed to look like this:

```
timestamp                           date          time     Hour      Minute
2018-01-17 10:35:00 UTC       2018-01-17      10:35:00       10          35
2015-05-08 17:30:00 UTC       2015-05-08      17:30:00       17          30      
2017-11-22 07:15:00 UTC       2017-11-22      07:15:00       07          15
2017-12-05 07:30:00 UTC       2017-12-05      07:30:00       07          30
```

Is there an easy way to do this with a package like `lubridate` or do I need to go through the effort of parsing out the data by 10 characters, then a space, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the accessors in `lubridate` to create the hour, minute and second columns. I am not clear what format you want the "time" column in. R supports datetimes and dates, but not just times. `lubridate` has three "time length" classes, the `period`, the `duration` and the `interval`. I picked `duration` here, which tracks physical time rather than clock time, but you can change as necessary.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
tbl <- tibble(
  timestamp = c(
    "2018-01-17 10:35:00 UTC",
    "2015-05-08 17:30:00 UTC",
    "2017-11-22 07:15:00 UTC",
    "2017-12-05 07:30:00 UTC"
  )
)

tbl %>%
  mutate(
    timestamp = ymd_hms(timestamp),
    date = date(timestamp),
    hours = hour(timestamp),
    minutes = minute(timestamp),
    seconds = second(timestamp),
    time = pmap(
      .l = list(hours, minutes, seconds),
      .f = ~ dhours(..1) + dminutes(..2) + dseconds(..3)
    )
  )
#> # A tibble: 4 x 6
#>   timestamp           date       hours minutes seconds time          
#>   <dttm>              <date>     <int>   <int>   <dbl> <list>        
#> 1 2018-01-17 10:35:00 2018-01-17    10      35       0 <S4: Duration>
#> 2 2015-05-08 17:30:00 2015-05-08    17      30       0 <S4: Duration>
#> 3 2017-11-22 07:15:00 2017-11-22     7      15       0 <S4: Duration>
#> 4 2017-12-05 07:30:00 2017-12-05     7      30       0 <S4: Duration>
```

Created on 2018-07-23 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `tidyverse` option using `purrr::map_df`

```
library(tidyverse)
bind_cols(df, map_df(
    c(date = "%Y/%m/%d", time = "%H:%M:%S", Hour = "%H", Minute = "%M"),
    ~format(as.POSIXct(df$timestamp), format = .x)))
#                timestamp       date     time Hour Minute
#1 2018-01-17 10:35:00 UTC 2018/01/17 10:35:00   10     35
#2 2015-05-08 17:30:00 UTC 2015/05/08 17:30:00   17     30
#3 2017-11-22 07:15:00 UTC 2017/11/22 07:15:00   07     15
#4 2017-12-05 07:30:00 UTC 2017/12/05 07:30:00   07     30
```

---

### Sample data

```
df <- read.table(text =
    "timestamp
'2018-01-17 10:35:00 UTC'
'2015-05-08 17:30:00 UTC'
'2017-11-22 07:15:00 UTC'
'2017-12-05 07:30:00 UTC'", header = T)
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Calum You's answer, but we could just use date, hour, and minute directly I suppose.

```
library(lubridate)
new <- df %>%
  mutate(date = date(ymd_hms(test$timestamp)), 
  time = format(ymd_hms(test$timestamp), format = c("%H:%M:%S")), 
  Hour = hour(ymd_hms(test$timestamp)),
  Minute = minute(ymd_hms(test$timestamp)))
```